# Как вывести число формата "__int64" с пробелами на разряды C++

Tags: c++, windows, printf

```
__int64 TotalNumberOfBytes;

BOOL GetDiskFreeSpaceFlag = GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(
    L"c:\\",                      // directory name
    NULL,     // bytes available to caller
    (PULARGE_INTEGER)&TotalNumberOfBytes,     // bytes on disk
    NULL  // free bytes on disk
);

if (GetDiskFreeSpaceFlag != 0)
{
    printf("\n\rОбщий объем: %I64d ( %I64d Mb )", TotalNumberOfBytes, TotalNumberOfBytes / 1024 / 1000);
}
else    printf("Отсутствует (GetDiskFreeSpace)");
```

Выводит:

> Общий объем: 249464614912 ( 243617 Mb )

Я хочу сделать:

> Общий объем: 249 464 614 912 ( 243617 Mb )

Хочу что бы выводилось с пробелами между разрядами, т.к. там выводятся большие числа, для удобства хочу что бы выводилось поразрядно. Как такое сделать?
Написано, что нужно использовать именно этот `__int64` (64-бита) тип для работы с такими большими числами.

Comment: Как бы вы вывели 32-битное число группами по три десятичных цифры? В сторону используйте `unsigned` тип такой как `ULONGLONG`

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Print integer with thousands and millions separator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17530408/4279)

Answer (score 3):

Можно сконфигурировать [`numpunct.thousands_sep`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct/thousands_sep):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

struct space_out : std::numpunct<char> {
    char do_thousands_sep()   const { return ' '; }  // separate with spaces
    std::string do_grouping() const { return "\3"; } // groups of 3 digit
};

int main()
{
  uint64_t u = 249464614912;
  std::cout << "default locale: " << u << '\n';
  std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new space_out));
  std::cout << "locale with modified numpunct: " << u << '\n';
}
```

Пример:

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 *.cc && ./a.out
default locale: 249464614912
locale with modified numpunct: 249 464 614 912
```